# Unity - Photon OnJoinedRoom not being called

Tags: android, networking, unity-game-engine, photon

I am using photon to make a FPS game for android.
Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SceneLoaderButton : Photon.PunBehaviour {


    public string roomName, mapNameGL, password;


    public GameObject loadingPan;

    public MenuRooms menuManager;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        Button btn = GetComponent<Button> ();
        btn.onClick.AddListener (ConnectCustomRoom);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void ConnectCustomRoom(){

        string room = roomName;

        RoomInfo[] ri;
        ri = PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList ();

        bool correct = false;

        string passwd, mapName = "";
        passwd = password;

        foreach (RoomInfo info in ri) {
            if (info.name == room) {
                if (info.customProperties ["Password"].ToString() == passwd) {
                    print(info.playerCount + "/" + info.maxPlayers);
                    if (info.playerCount < info.maxPlayers)
                    {
                        correct = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        menuManager.error("No room for you");
                    }
                    mapName = info.customProperties ["MapName"].ToString ();
                }
                else
                {
                    menuManager.error("Incorrect password");
                }
            }
        }
        mapNameGL = mapName;
        print(mapNameGL);

        if (correct) {
            print("Correct");
            loadingPan.active = !loadingPan.active;
            PhotonNetwork.playerName = "Player" + UnityEngine.Random.Range (1000,9999).ToString();
            PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(room);
        }
    }


    void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        print("Joined room: " + roomName);
        //We joined room, load respective map
        Application.LoadLevel(mapNameGL);
    }
}
```

This is the code from  button. It is instantiated and it should join the room, then load the scene. In other scripts, "onjoinedroom" callback works, even if I inherite from Photon.MonoBehaveiour, not from PUNBehaveiour. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on PUN documentation, it is a virtual member, so you can override that method.

try to change the method to :

```
override void OnJoinedRoom ()
{
//your codes
}
//or
public override void OnJoinedRoom ()
{
//your codes
}
```

> This class provides a .photonView and all callbacks/events that PUN
>   can call. Override the events/methods you want to use. By extending
>   this class, you can implement individual methods as override.

Hope that's help you.

Reference :
[PUN Documentation](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/class_photon_1_1_pun_behaviour.html#a8ee05dd443b9e51ddf962e655ca8ab77)